# Can any one help me with "pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results. Previous SQL was not a query." This is the error I am getting

Tags: python, sql-server-2008-r2

import pyodbc
cnxn = 
`enter code here` pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}',
server='cdcbopex',
database='PMLData',
uid='pml_manisha',
pwd='*******')

class DBConnector:
`enter code here` def **init**(self, cnxn, cursor):
self.cnxn = cnxn
self.cursor = cursor

## Insert Excel sheet values Into Tables

```
def insertValues(self, row, head):
    insertStr = "('"
    headStr = '('
    for item in self.head:
        item = str(item).replace("#", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(" ", "").replace("-", "")
        headStr = headStr + item + ","
    headStr = headStr[:-1] + ")"
    for item in row:
        item = str(item).replace("\n", "").replace("'", "")
        insertStr = insertStr + item + "','"
    insertStr = insertStr[:-2] + ");"
    queryStr = "INSERT INTO " + head + " " + headStr + " VALUES " + insertStr
    self.cursor.execute(queryStr)
    self.cursor.commit()
    return queryStr
```

## Creating Table in database

```
def newTable(self, cols, name):
    queryStr = "CREATE TABLE " + name + "("
    for col in cols:
        col = str(col).replace("#", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(" ", "").replace("-", "")
        queryStr = queryStr + col + " varchar(150),"
    queryStr = queryStr[:-1] + ");"
    self.cursor.execute(queryStr)
    self.cursor.commit()
    return queryStr
```